# Image overlay on video in iOS safari

Tags: ios, html, video

The iOS system seems take the control of video playing in browser. And it will 'raise' the video to the most front.

So, is there any method that can overlay image on video which played by iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No not from HTML5. Mobile Safari on the iPhone will always play the movie full screen.

Answer (score 1):

in iOS 10 and above, you can use the `playsinline` attribute, then the overlays are being displayed. haven't checked interactivity though.

From https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/:

> On iPhone, `<video playsinline>` elements will now be allowed to play inline, and will not automatically enter fullscreen mode when playback begins.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to just overlay an image, this works:

http://jsbin.com/ajivex/1

Unfortunately it's not clickable, which is my current problem.

Comment: @RayShih IOS6?  the X image on the top right shows up on IOS5 and IOS6.  It wasn't clickable on 5, but is on 6.

Comment: iOS 6 on iPhone 4S.
The X image will show before the video play. Once the video start playing, it will become fullscreen mode and couldn't see the image. (at least on my iphone)